# How to properly Release BitmapBuffer from SoftwareBitmap (UWP)?

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-10-universal, c++-cx, windows-10-iot-core

I struggle to properly release the `BitmapBuffer` locked with `SoftwareBitmap.LockBuffer()` method in C++/CX code on UWP.

The base code looks as below (it's a OpenCV bridge sample from Microsoft available [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/CameraOpenCV/shared/OpenCVBridge/OpenCVHelper.cpp).

```
bool OpenCVHelper::GetPointerToPixelData(SoftwareBitmap^ bitmap, unsigned char** pPixelData, unsigned int* capacity)
{
   BitmapBuffer^ bmpBuffer = bitmap->LockBuffer(BitmapBufferAccessMode::ReadWrite);
   IMemoryBufferReference^ reference = bmpBuffer->CreateReference();

   ComPtr<IMemoryBufferByteAccess> pBufferByteAccess;
   if ((reinterpret_cast<IInspectable*>(reference)->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pBufferByteAccess))) != S_OK)
   {
    return false;
   }

   if (pBufferByteAccess->GetBuffer(pPixelData, capacity) != S_OK)
   {
    return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

This buffer (`pPixelData`) is then used to initialize `cv:Mat` object (shallow copy). And is never released.

Consecutive call to `LockBuffer()` on the same `SoftwareBitmap` object raises exception:

> Platform::AccessDeniedException ^ at memory location 0x00000002CEEFDCC0. HRESULT:0x80070005 Access is denied.
>   WinRT information: Bitmap shared lock taken

How to properly release this buffer? Especially in C++/CX?

I tried to keep the reference to release it when no more needed. In C++/CX Dispose() or Close() methods are inaccessible and compiler advises to call destructor instead:

```
BitmapBuffer^ bmpBuffer = nullptr;
// ... get the buffer, use it
//((IDisposable^)bmpBuffer)->Dispose();
bmpBuffer->~BitmapBuffer();
```

But it doesn't work (does nothing). Destructor is being invoked but another call to LockBuffer() raises the same error as before.

Comment: I am not sure why you need explicitly release `pPixelData` buffer. But if you want to do this you can release it where it created and it created in this function `OpenCVHelper::TryConvert` at this line: `unsigned char* pPixels = nullptr;`.  You can release it like this `pPixels = nullptr;` before `return true;`. Actually, it will be released automatically after its function ends because it is a local variable.

Comment: Not the pPixelData, but the bmpBuffer (BitmapBuffer). The reason is to release the lock acquired with LockBuffer() method. Otherwise it works only once (I havent found any information in the documentation, that once you use LockBuffer() you cant release it).

Answer (score 0):

> How to properly Release BitmapBuffer from SoftwareBitmap (UWP)?

After `BitmapBuffer` and `IMemoryBufferReference` completing their work, these objects could be closed by invoking `delete` expression. More details please check [Destructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/ref-classes-and-structs-c-cx#destructors). For example:

```
SoftwareBitmap^ bitmap = ref new SoftwareBitmap(
    BitmapPixelFormat::Bgra8,
    100,
    200,
    BitmapAlphaMode::Premultiplied);
BitmapBuffer^ bmpBuffer = bitmap->LockBuffer(BitmapBufferAccessMode::ReadWrite); 
IMemoryBufferReference^ reference = bmpBuffer->CreateReference();
delete reference;
delete bmpBuffer; 
BitmapBuffer^ bmpBuffer2 = bitmap->LockBuffer(BitmapBufferAccessMode::ReadWrite);
```

As above code snippet showed, after delete the `BitmapBuffer` object, you could lock the buffer again successfully.

Comment: In your example the two LockBuffers just happen to be in the same scope. Normally, and in the Pawels case too, manually deleting the objects should not be needed. The BitmapBuffer^ reference is automatically released once it is out of scope, and when there are no more references the object itself is deleted. Pawel's code must be holding on to a reference somewhere. Consider what will happen with those, once underlying object is forcibly destroyed.

Comment: This is interesting, because in OP function, if the `BitmapBufer^` et al are automatically released, then the `char **` return value is immediately invalid, based on the description of how those objects function, i.e. calling `IDispose` "releases" the buffer lock.  To me the `GetPointerToPixelData` must work by accident, because of how it's scoped, i.e. i cannot actually use those "output" values outside of scope where they were acquired, because everyone got disposed already.

That is how it works in C# everything is in a `using`.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the above `GetPointerToPixelData` (and the `TryConvert`) successfully in a Windows Store app (12 months now), so maybe in the years since OP, the framework has improved, or maybe I'm using it differently.

However, this code always "bothered" me, so here is my journey putting the world to rights....

If we were using these directly in managed C#, all the examples clearly show `using` on both the `BitmapBuffer` and the `IMemoryBufferReference` so calling the `IDispose` ASAP seems to me to be obligatory.  The documentation even admonishes you to not hold onto these very long!

Now that I understand how these APIs work better, IMHO the UWP sample code works "by accident" (it's a *sample* after all, so no judgment), so I finally decided to re-implement so everything is scoped properly (with RAII) and uses a closure for the "action", so now we also clean up if an `Exception` occurs in the `handler`.

This version also accounts for the `Stride` which is important when you are dealing with GREY images, which my app handles (got tired of calling `cvtColor` on everything...)

> Disclaimer: I know enough C++/CX to be dangerous; this can probably be improved by someone who knows the "rules" better.

> Edited: modified `stride` handling to use the ctor overload.  Switched to `void`. Switched to `const` closure parameter. Added error control.

```
void OpenCVHelper::UseBitmap(SoftwareBitmap^ sb, BitmapBufferAccessMode bbam, std::function<void(const Mat&)> handler) {
    // invokes IDispose (via delete) at end-of-scope
    disposer<BitmapBuffer^> bb(sb->LockBuffer(bbam));
    IMemoryBufferReference^ imbr = bb->CreateReference();
    disposer<IMemoryBufferReference^> xx(imbr);
    ComPtr<IMemoryBufferByteAccess> pmbba;
    bool error = true;
    if ((reinterpret_cast<IInspectable*>(imbr)->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pmbba))) == S_OK) {
        unsigned char* pPixels = nullptr;
        unsigned int capacity = 0;
        if (pmbba->GetBuffer(&pPixels, &capacity) == S_OK) {
            size_t stride = Mat::AUTO_STEP;
            int width = sb->PixelWidth;
            int height = sb->PixelHeight;
            if (sb->BitmapPixelFormat == BitmapPixelFormat::Gray8 && bb->GetPlaneCount() > 0) {
                BitmapPlaneDescription bpd = bb->GetPlaneDescription(0);
                stride = (size_t)bpd.Stride;
                width = bpd.Width;
                height = bpd.Height;
            }
            int type = TypeFor(sb->BitmapPixelFormat);
            Mat mat(height, width, type, (void*)pPixels, stride);
            try {
                handler(mat);
                error = false;
            }
            catch(cv::Exception cex) {
                throw ref new Platform::FailureException(std_to_managed((std::string)cex.msg));
            }
        }
    }
    if(error) throw ref new Platform::FailureException("Failed to attach the SoftwareBitmap");
}
```

The `TypeFor` write your own or hard-code BGRA8. If you only care about BGRA8 the `Stride` stuff is unnecessary; BGRA is 4-byte aligned.  Also note we need to use `Platform` exceptions back to managed-land.

I should have been able to use `std::unique_ptr` to get it to invoke the `operator delete` for me, but it doesn't work with `ref` classes.

I also had trouble with getting the `finally` helper to work with `ref` classes (`ref` classes are taint) so built an abbreviated version to handle the lack of `try/finally` in C++ and went the RAII route (as required).  Here is `disposer`:

```
template <class F>
class disposer {
public:
    explicit disposer(F inst) noexcept :f_(inst) {};
    ~disposer() noexcept {
        delete f_;
    }
    F operator->() const { return f_; }
private:
    F f_;
};
```

Setting a breakpoint verifies that `delete` is called with correct order and timing.

For extra credit, here is a use case; most "operations" require 2 bitmaps, one for input and one for output, so here is a helper function that takes a closure that receives both `Mat&` instances:

```
void OpenCVHelper::Use2Bitmaps(Windows::Graphics::Imaging::SoftwareBitmap^ sb1,
    Windows::Graphics::Imaging::BitmapBufferAccessMode bbam1,
    Windows::Graphics::Imaging::SoftwareBitmap^ sb2,
    Windows::Graphics::Imaging::BitmapBufferAccessMode bbam2,
    std::function<void(const cv::Mat&, const cv::Mat&)> handler) {
    OpenCVHelper::UseBitmap(sb1, bbam1, [&](const Mat& mat1) {
        OpenCVHelper::UseBitmap(sb2, bbam2, [&handler, &mat1](const Mat& mat2) {
            handler(mat1, mat2);
        });
    });
}
```

And finally, here is an actual use case calling CV APIs:

```
void OpenCVHelper::Linear(
    Windows::Graphics::Imaging::SoftwareBitmap^ input,
    double alpha, double beta,
    Windows::Graphics::Imaging::SoftwareBitmap^ output) {
    OpenCVHelper::Use2Bitmaps(input, BitmapBufferAccessMode::Read, output, BitmapBufferAccessMode::ReadWrite, [&](const Mat& src, const Mat& dst) {
        src.convertTo(dst, -1, alpha, beta);
    });
}
```